# How do I open a built-in tutorial in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I just downloaded Eclipse. The welcome page asked if I'd like to follow through a tutorial, so I happily started. However, at one point, I right clicked and somehow closed the tutorial, and now I cannot figure out how to re-open the tutorial. I've gone through most of the options under "Show View" and tried restarting the IDE to get the welcome page again, but none of these have worked.

Where on the IDE can I open a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Eclipse's tutorials are called "Cheat Sheets". In order to open a cheat sheet, navigate to `Help->Cheat Sheets...` and select the one you'd like to follow through.

[image]